# "I think if we DO NOT enough resources..." why use "do" instead of "have" (“ I think if we HAVE NOT…)?

Tags: grammar

> "I think if we **do not** enough resources..."

Why use "do" instead of "have"?

> "I think if we **have not** ..."

I didn't understand why to use **"do"** instead of the verb "**have"**. Could you explain to me how to use **"do"** in these cases?

Comment: Where have you found that sentence? It doesn't seem idiomatic, it lacks a main verb. "I think if we do not get enough resources", "I think if we do not obtain", "I think if we do not have enough resources" ,... are all valid. Notice that "have" is an auxiliary verb, if it's used as the main verb [possess, own, or hold], it needs "do" to construct the negative tense

Comment: Can you edit your question to enter a verb after "do not" please.

Comment: Thank you RubioRic for your answer! Is not an idiomatic sentence, I was talking with a person and she has corrected me in this way but I remained confused..

Comment: The sentence you are quoting is not anyone would say on purpose. I suspect they misspoke in the heat of the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It is an error.

The obvious correction would be "... do not have enough resources..."

Saying "... have not..." is only used when "have" is used as a helping verb in the perfect tenses.  When it is a main verb, the negation is is "don't have".

Comment: I just do not get why people get their knickers in a twist when it's obviously a typo.

Comment: Because the OP isn't able to tell it is a typo. The OP thinks that "have" has been substituted by "do".  In fact it there is no substitution.  There is an omission. The word "have" has been omitted.

Comment: James, I meant the others, not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

English has the notion of "do-support", which means *{form of do} + {infintive form of verb}* is used in certain situations.

Those situations are:

- Emphasis with verbs other than *to be*
- Questions with verbs other than *to be*
- Use of *not*, with verbs other than *to be*.

The following "overrides" the *do* in these situations:

- Modals
- *Have* as part of the perfect tenses

Emphasis:

> I did go to the park today.
>
> I would go to the park today.
>
> He has walked to the park before.
>
> I really am at the park (you can't use *do* to emphasize)

Question:

> Did you walk to the park?
>
> Would you walk to the park?
>
> Have you walked to the park before?
>
> Am I at the park?

Use of *not*:

> I did not go to the park today.
>
> I would not go to the park today.
>
> I have not gone to the park today.